# How can I redirect from one subdomain to another in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Recently we changed the name of a subdomain, now we need to redirect all the old pages to the new subdomain pages.

Example page links:

- Old URL: http://jquery.webcodehelpers.com/2013/08/what-does-dollar-sign-means-in-jquery.html
- New URL: http://uieiq.webcodehelpers.com/2013/08/what-does-dollar-sign-means-in-jquery.html

My findings: when I try to access the subdomain in the top level it is working good.

How can I redirect all URLs on the old subdomain to the new subdomain?

currently i have the below code in .htaccess file , please guide to solve the problem

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jquery\.webcodehelpers\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.jquery\.webcodehelpers\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/uieiq\.webcodehelpers\.com\/search\/label\/jquery\ interview\ questions" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jquery\.webcodehelpers\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://uieiq.webcodehelpers.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

#### Please read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: hi anubhava, i added but still it is not working, code in .htaccess file
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jquery\.webcodehelpers\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://uieiq.webcodehelpers.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName webcodehelpers.com
AuthUserFile /home/webcodeh/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/webcodeh/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

Comment: Please don't post code in comment, its not readable at all. Edit your question and post your code there.

Comment: Also make sure to have above code in the **DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess file of jquery.webcodehelpers.com host**

Comment: hey anubhava, i added my htaccess file code in the question, please help me how to modifiy that

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, and maintains the URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jquery\.webcodehelpers\.com
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://uieiq.webcodehelpers.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I used this to redirect a subdomain to another subdomain.

Comment: I was not able to get %{REQUEST_URI} to work as suggested in another post.